# Create a calendar link for Outlook Office 365 calendar?

Tags: calendar, office365-apps

I can create a link that populates my Google calendar with information, like this...

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=MyEvent&dates=20150701T000000Z/20160305T000000Z&details=Test&location=Somewhere">Add to Google Calendar</a>
```

...which works fine. But how can I create one that does the same thing but works for web based Outlook Office 365 calendar? Information on how to do this is surprisingly scarce.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of official documentation for this, but I believe the link format should be as follows:

```
https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?body=description&enddt=2022-04-01T13%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00&location=location&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2022-04-01T13%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=title
```

or to make that a bit more readable:

```
https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose
   ?body=description
   &enddt=2022-04-01T13%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00
   &location=location
   &path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose
   &rru=addevent
   &startdt=2022-04-01T13%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
   &subject=title
```

The date times above are URL Encoded so before encoding would look like:

```
2022-04-01T13:30:00+00:00
```

Should be self-explanatory (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+zz:zz) the last bit after the + is the time offset from UTC (hh:mm) of the timezone.

Source:
https://www.labnol.org/apps/calendar.html